# How do I embed a java swing applet into a website?

Tags: java, html, swing, netbeans, applet

I am trying to embed a swing applet into our website, but it is not working. I have been able to get applets that use awt to do graphics to work. The web page that contains the applet only shows a blank box that should contain my applet, there aren't even any error messages. My applet works fine in netbeans. The applet is supposed to show a few buttons and a text field. I really don't know whats going on.

The web page is located at http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/GUIApplet.html
The applet is at http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/TestApplet.jar

Here is the html:

```
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Test Page</title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       </head>
       <body>
           <applet Archive ="TestApplet.jar, swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"
                  Code="test.GUIApplet"
                  WIDTH="250" HEIGHT="300" >
           </applet>

       </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Works for me! :) (btw `arhive` attribute should be a comma separated list and you have a ` ` (space) there also)

Comment: wow, it works for you? Something must be up with my browser.

Comment: 2 buttons and a text field, right?   Works fine in IE, blank page in FF.  But then, my FF on this Win 7 based Netbook is failing for all applets at the moment.  :(   BTW - with the HTML, and a link to the live page and Jar - excellent question.  +1

Answer (score 3):

as I wrote in the comments it works for me (I'm using OpenJDK 1.6.0_22, Linux (ubuntu) and Firefox).

If java works from your "command line" or terminal. I could be that the plugin for your browser isn't installed. I would recommend you reinstalling the [JDK or JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and remember to install the plugin for the browser aswell.

Comment: I found that it doesn't work from my mac, but does from a pc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<object>` tag instead. To know how to use this, check this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#object)